# C++11 type-conversion heisenbug when using std::string::c_str()

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion, xcode6

This is very strange.

OSX 10.10
LLVM 6.0
XCode 6.1

```
test_assert("Wierd", String{"ABC"}, "ABC" ); // claims not equal
```

String is my custom class (wrapping a Python String primitive), and it should pass this test.

Here's test_assert, with added debug output:

```
template <typename B, typename V>
static void test_assert( std::string description, B benchmark, V value )
{
    std::ostringstream full_description;

    full_description << description
        << " : { " << "benchmark"      << ", " << "value"          << " }"
        << " = { " << typeid(B).name() << ", " << typeid(V).name() << " }"
        << " , { " << benchmark        << ", " << value            << " }";

    // N2Py6StringE, PKc  i.e. Py::String and const char* (Pointer to Konst Char)
    std::cout << typeid(B).name() << ", " << typeid(V).name() << std::endl;

    V b_as_v{static_cast<V>(benchmark)};

    // wtf? b_as_v: \352\277_\377 -- should be "ABC"
    std::cout << "b_as_v: " << b_as_v << std::endl; // Y

    if( b_as_v == value )
        std::cout << "    PASSED: " << full_description.str() << std::endl;
    else
        throw TestError( full_description.str() );
}
```

It is this `b_as_v{static_cast<V>(benchmark)};` that is throwing me, because if I single step into it, it correctly takes me to String's 'convert to const char*' operator, which performs its duty correctly:

```
class String : Object {
    explicit operator const char*()                                                    const
    {
        std::string s{ as_std_string() };
        const char* c{ s.c_str() };

        // c before return: ABC
        std::cout << "c before return: " << c << std::endl; // X

        return c;
    }
    :
```

Now this is the weird thing: if line X is in place, line Y reports nothing: 'b_as_v: '

Removing it, line Y reports the original: 'b_as_v: \352\277_\377'

In fact, just printing `std::cout << std::endl; // X'` for X is sufficient to clear output from Y (however, moving X' to immediately in front of Y restores the original behaviour).

So it seems that the act of observation modifies the return value.

A heisenbug >:|

And neither behaviour is the desired one.

Another weirdness is that there is an extra Unicode character that copies to my clipboard at the end of '\352\277_\377' if I copy paste from Xcode's console to the SO text edit window.

[image]

Even if I only select the last `7` it still copies across, even though it doesn't take up a whitespace in Xcode's console.

(This extra character doesn't show up on the SO question, in fact it is no longer there when I reopen the question for editing.  It isn't a
 newline character --I've tested copy-paste-ing in the last character of a particular line)

I have tried to create a testcase, but it performs sadly as I would expect: http://ideone.com/gbyU6Y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fairly complicated setup, but the cause is rather straightforward:

```
explicit operator const char*() const
{
    std::string s{ as_std_string() };
    const char* c{ s.c_str() };

    // c before return: ABC
    std::cout << "c before return: " << c << std::endl; // X

    return c;
}
```

The pointer returned by `std::string::c_str()` points into the `std::string`'s internal storage, and so can be invalidated for a number of reasons - the destruction of the `std::string` object being one of them. Here, `c` is invalidated as soon as your conversion function returns and `s` is destroyed, meaning that a dangling pointer is returned.

Also, libc++ uses the small-string optimization, meaning that a string as short as `"ABC"` is stored inside the `std::string` object itself (in this case, on the stack), rather than in dynamically allocated storage. This makes it much more likely that the space that used to be occupied by the string could be reused before your code attempt to print it.

Comment: Thanks T.C., does this mean that the only way I can safely return a const char* is by malloc-ing it, and requiring the consumer to subsequently free it?

Comment: @Pi Or store a `std::string` inside your `String` class, perhaps. Or just return a `std::string` and have the consumer call `.c_str()` on it.